# CalendarView getDate method returns current date, not selected date... What am I doing wrong?

Tags: android, calendarview

My calendarView fails to return the selected date, instead returning some default that always points to today.

I am of course changing the date selected in my calendar, and it indeed displays as having changed. I tried inspecting the view in debug mode, but didn't find anything.

I am running this in a simulator, not on a real phone... Should I modify some settings? Am I missing something important? Because it really is confusing that I'm not getting the selected date, but the current one.

```
<CalendarView
                            android:id="@+id/view_calendar_create_event_date"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />
```

This is called from the event listener

```
protected void createEvent(View view){
        TextView eventNameView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.createEventNameInput);
        String eventName = eventNameView.getEditableText().toString();

        CalendarView eventOccursOnView = (CalendarView) this.findViewById(R.id.view_calendar_create_event_date);
        long eventOccursOn = eventOccursOnView.getDate();
        Date temporary = new Date(eventOccursOn);

        Event newEvent = new Event(eventName, "", 0, 0, eventOccursOn);
        newEvent.save(view.getContext());
    }
```

and this is how I'm setting my event listener

```
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Create the event
                EventDetailsActivity.this.createEvent(view);

                // Notify the user
                Snackbar.make(view, "Successfully created a new event!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();

                // Return to the previous activity
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to implement `setOnDateChangeListener`

```
long eventOccursOn;

eventOccursOnView.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {
    //show the selected date as a toast
    @Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int day) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), day + "/" + month + "/" + year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(year, month, day);
        eventOccursOn = c.getTimeInMillis(); //this is what you want to use later
    }
 });
```

Comment: That was it... Do you have any idea why the calendarview behaves like this? It is a little unexpected (to say the least). Furthermore it is not documented. I found this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html#getDate()  which explicitly says that it gets the selected date, NOT the current one.... Do you know if this a bug or if I'm missing something?

Comment: glad I helped, this not a bug . It is working as it is mentioned in documentation . By default the selected date is the today's date . When you change the date actually you are not selecting any new date , rather than you are changing the selected date  and you can grab that action on setOnDateChangeListener .

Answer (score 0):

This is my understanding and solution:

by default CalendarView's selected date is today. When you select new day in calendar, it's just highlighted in view, but not actually selected (I know, doesn't make sense, but this is how this view works).
So you need to implement date change listener and inside it select new date in calendar view.

```
import java.util.Calendar
import java.util.Date

// assuming your CalendarView has id 'calendarView'
fun initCalendarView() {
   // prints today's date by default
   printCurrentlySelectedDate()

   binding.calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener { _, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
      binding.calendarView.date = Calendar.getInstance()
         .apply { set(year, month, dayOfMonth) }
         .timeInMillis
   }
}

fun consumeSelectedDate() {
   // now date is whatever you selected in view
   printCurrentlySelectedDate()
}

fun printCurrentlySelectedDate() {
   val date = Date(binding.calendarView.date)
   println(date)
}
```