# Using CalendarView with databinding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-livedata, calendarview

I want to use two-way databinding with Android `LiveData` components ([as an alternative for Observable fields](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-livedata-with-data-binding-7bf85871bbd8). Here's code for simple project with `CalendarView` and `EditText` that displays both info on button clicked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
<data>
    <variable
        name="testDate"
        type="android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData&lt;Long&gt;" />
    <variable
        name="testString"
        type="android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData&lt;String&gt;" />
</data>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:text="Show data"/>

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/cal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:date="@={testDate}"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/str"
        android:text="@={testString}"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

And activity code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

val liveDate = MutableLiveData<Long>().apply { value = System.currentTimeMillis() }
val liveString = MutableLiveData<String>().apply { value = "Date: " }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
            .also {
                it.testDate = liveDate
                it.testString = liveString

                it.cal.setOnDateChangeListener { view, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "${view.date}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

            }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
fun onButtonClick(view: View) {
    Toast.makeText(this, liveString.value +
            Instant.ofEpochMilli(liveDate.value!!).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate()
            , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show()
}
}
```

Two-way binding works fine for String, but not for the date. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46144150/calendarview-getdate-method-returns-current-date-not-selected-date-what-am-i), which says that selected date is actually something different from the date used by `android:date`... Fair enough, you can capture this action of changing the date in the listener. The problem is that listener `setOnDateChangeListener` (applied in `also {}` above) is not triggered at all, when there is a two-way binding setup.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but if I want to get the selected date *I have to* use `OnDateChangeListener`. It also appears to be incompatible with `android:date@={...}` because using two-way binding seems to override our listener. It would make sense if `android:date@={...}` provided the same functionality as `OnDateChangeListener`, but it does not.

So the final question is: is it possible to get the selected date somehow with two-way databinding?

Comment: Hi Luke, did you check my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### There are bunch of bugs, which I found after tracking all classes.

#### Bug 1

This is bug of Android Documentation. See [CalendarViewBindingAdapter](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/3b920788e90bb0abe615a5d5c899915f0014444b/extensions/baseAdapters/src/main/java/android/databinding/adapters/CalendarViewBindingAdapter.java) class.

You can see they have created binding adapter for `android:date`, but there is no `@InverseBindingAdapter`.

```
@BindingAdapter({"android:date"})
public static void setDate(CalendarView view, long date) {
    if (view.getDate() != date) {
        view.setDate(date);
    }
}

// no @InverseBindingAdapter written
```

But on [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way), they have written that `CalendarView` supports two-way binding.

Perhaps we will get this in next updates.

I also tried to add `@InverseBindingAdapter` but that was not working too.

```
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:date", event = "android:dateAttrChanged")
public static long getDateLong(CalendarView view) {
    return view.getDate();
}
```

#### Bug 2

Try setting `setOnDateChangeListener` on `CalendarView`, you will get same date always.

**Below does not work**

```
binding.cal.setOnDateChangeListener((view, year, month, dayOfMonth) -> {
     Log.d(TAG, "aLong: " + new Date(view.getDate()).toString());
});
```

**Below works**

```
binding.cal.setOnDateChangeListener((view, year, month, dayOfMonth) -> {
    Log.d(TAG, "aLong: " + new Date(year, month, dayOfMonth).toString());
});
```

#### That's why my `@InverseBindingAdapter` does not work.

Because `calendarView.getDate()` is not giving correct date.

## Fix

You can fix this by creating your adapter till they don't fix this issue. Just put below class in your project, and everything will work well.

```
public class CalendarViewBindingAdapter {
    @BindingAdapter(value = {"android:onSelectedDayChange", "android:dateAttrChanged"},
            requireAll = false)
    public static void setListeners(CalendarView view, final CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener onDayChange,
                                    final InverseBindingListener attrChange) {
        if (attrChange == null) {
            view.setOnDateChangeListener(onDayChange);
        } else {
            view.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,
                                                int dayOfMonth) {
                    if (onDayChange != null) {
                        onDayChange.onSelectedDayChange(view, year, month, dayOfMonth);
                    }
                    Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
                    instance.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
                    view.setDate(instance.getTimeInMillis());
                    attrChange.onChange();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

#### What I fixed

I just set date to CalendarView (`view.setDate()`), which was 0 previously.

Comment: So we have to implement something that's supposed to be out of the box since binding for `android:data` is useless. I gave up two way binding and just simply used listener to build a date from year / month /day. Thanks for posting.

Comment: Yes, data binding is used for ease, if we are facing some bug, then we have old weapons too. :)